# Would I use an ORM if I am using Stored Procedures?

Tags: stored-procedures, orm

If I use stored procedures, can I use an ORM?

EDIT:

If I can use a ORM, doesn't that defeat part of the database agnosticity reason for using an ORM?  In other words, why else would I want to use an ORM, if I am binding myself to a particular database with stored procedures (or is that assumption wrong)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using ORM to access stored procedures is one of the best uses of ORM.  It'll give you strongly typed objects, while you still have full control over the SQL.

Comment: Which is fine IF your language that is strongly typed. When you're using something like PHP, you need code that checks your params. Thats does not mean that you can't have an ORM or code generator which won't do that for you. Example case: I developed a code generator which writes access wrappers for Postgresql functions and exposes them as a SOAP web service. Because I did not want to write extra code to check the scalar params, I added a functions which does it because PHP does not support scalar type hinting (https://github.com/sylnsr/pgfunc2php/blob/master/pgsupport.lib.php)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience I would let the ORM handle the 'CRUD' operations, and leave the specialty work to the stored procedures.  Generally, using a stored procedure for 'CRUD' operations is overkill, and to let the ORM handle it, could drastically improve your productivity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, all main ORMs support stored procedures.

As for your assumption, you are particulary right, when you use stored procedures with ORM you are coupling your project to a particular database. But in practice it is 99% that you will not need to change your database provider, so in this case you use ORM not to abstract from concrete DB provider, but to help yourself with object-relational mapping task - which is a main ORM's task and which ORM was originally made for.

Answer (score 2):

It raises an interesting point.

Once you have ORM, and relatively simple queries, why do you need stored procedures?  SP's are intimately bound to the database.  ORM frees you from having to maintain a lot of DB-specific code.  What *is* DB-specific can be isolated and managed.

I suggest that an ORM is a golden chance to cut the complexity and put all the processing in the code where it belongs.

Use the database for what it does best -- store data.

Use your application for what it does best -- process data.

Comment: Isn't this a huge debate though? SP versus no SP.

Comment: Some people like to debate it.  Others of us are tired of trying to maintain broken stored procedure and trigger tangles of junk.  The idea the ORM liberates from the complexity of SP's is very appealing to some of us.

Comment: If they are really 'simple queries', there's no problem. There's much SP abuse already. The problem begins when the application is abused and execute processing that's obviously partain to the DB server realm - dealing with large resultsets. When you need to throw 50k rows in the network just to obey the 'Use your application for what it does best -- process data' idea - like a religious dogma - it's obvious that processing is better serviced on a stored procedure.

Comment: "Use your application for what it does best -- process data." --> Mmmm all the top RDBMS are GREAT at processing data and will do it faster than your application. SQL exists not only to store data, but also to process it. I would say that your reasoning applies to certain NoSQL databases that do not support data processing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both ORM features and stored procedures functionality at once. Particularly use ORM until it fits you, but if you have some trouble with performance or need some low level tune - include stored procedures in your business-logic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you will want to spend some time investigating what capabilities the ORM provides around stored procedures.

Most will allow you to run a stored procedure that returns a strongly typed object / entity. More advanced ORM's will allow you to plug stored procedures in for performing CRUD actions as well (so your generic querying, deleting etc goes via a stored procedure rather than a dynamic query).

Generally ORM's are great for generating ad-hoc queries and getting strongly typed entities but having strong stored procedure support has the benefit of allowing you to (sometimes) more easily access native capability of your RDMS that may not be exposed as first class citizens in the ORM - especially if the ORM supports many database engines.

Following up from your edit:

Often you will want to use the ad-hoc querying engine provided by the ORM however as I alluded to earlier - sometimes you want to query using a capability not exposed from the ORM.

The benefits of strongly typed entities is invaluable as it means you have domain object usually, rather than data readers, data tables etc. You can cleanly encapsulate behaviors and logic within those entities that you have retrieved.

The list of additional benefits is very long indeed - for example, with the LightSpeed ORM (and most others) your entities will support standard binding interfaces, error reporting interfaces, validation etc. On the querying side you will lose out on lazy loading etc unless you write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Database "agnosticity" (?) is not the only reason to use an ORM. However, you could take advantage of being DB independent on 99% of your interactions with the DB and in 1% (or 2% or 10% or whatever) you might need stored procedures for speed/clarity/complexity. If you changed DBs, you would need to rewrite those.

Answer (score 1):

I use netTiers a lot at work and we let it generate our stored procedures for us.  These only handle the basic CRUD operations, but they are very fast and save me a TON of time.  netTiers will also let us create custom stored procedures and generate our data access code with these procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but many of the more advanced ORM features tend to become more cumbersome to use.  Something like [iBatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/) is very easy to integrate with stored procedures, while the more sophisticated features of more complex engines like (N?)Hibernate like generation of dynamic SQL and lazy loading of large fields can become more of a hassle than they're worth.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that any tool that frees you from redoing work and concentrate in solving the problems is valid. ORMs appear to be that tool when it come to basic CRUD operations - even if using SPs to better implement a requirement (like using a hammer on a nail, it's just the right tool for task).

The point is: there's no black or white, just a scale of gray. Very inneficient  and badly coded applications use the excuse of being 'DB agnostic' to explain the exagerated use of DB resources. In many cases, being very tied to a database is not good too. The objective is: getting maximum 'DB agnosticism' while not wasting customer IT resources without need.

There's no 'old vs new', just people saying that extreme 'pure' approaches are better. I don't really believe so. I believe that, as with any tool, the 'best' (notice the quotes) approach is using ORM until still is the right tool to make your data access. And use SPs inside your ORM when you reach a point where you're wasting resources and reducing scalability and 'worth life' (I forgot the english expression equivalent for the portuguese 'vida útil') of TI resources. Or, in other words, use SP when it's for the processing at hand what a hammer is for the nail.